# Nexus OSS - Unable to browse repository

Tags: nexus

We have an internal Nexus OSS repository running version 3.13.0-01.

When i am trying to browse one of the largest feed's, i recently get a popup saying

```
Error on execution of command: sql.select from browse_node where (repository_name=:repository_name and parent_path>=:subtree_boundary and parent_path<:base_boundary) limit 1 DB name="component"
```

While doing that, the following is logged in the log file

```
2020-07-24 14:10:03,540+0100 ERROR [pool-21-thread-1]  username org.sonatype.nexus.extdirect.internal.ExtDirectServlet - Failed to invoke action method: coreui_Browse.read, java-method: org.sonatype.nexus.coreui.BrowseComponent.read
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Error on execution of command: sql.select from browse_node where (repository_name=:repository_name and parent_path>=:subtree_boundary and parent_path<:base_boundary) limit 1
    DB name="component"
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.executeCommand(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:3421)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.command(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:3318)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandRequestTextAbstract.execute(OCommandRequestTextAbstract.java:69)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.BrowseNodeEntityAdapter.getByPath(BrowseNodeEntityAdapter.java:415)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.BrowseNodeStoreImpl.lambda$10(BrowseNodeStoreImpl.java:254)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.orient.transaction.OrientOperations.lambda$1(OrientOperations.java:56)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.transaction.OperationPoint.proceed(OperationPoint.java:64)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.transaction.TransactionalWrapper.proceedWithTransaction(TransactionalWrapper.java:56)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.transaction.Operations.transactional(Operations.java:200)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.transaction.Operations.call(Operations.java:146)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.orient.transaction.OrientOperations.call(OrientOperations.java:56)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.BrowseNodeStoreImpl.getByPath(BrowseNodeStoreImpl.java:253)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.BrowseNodeStoreImpl.getByPath(BrowseNodeStoreImpl.java:217)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.MethodInvocationAction.run(MethodInvocationAction.java:39)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.StateGuard$GuardImpl.run(StateGuard.java:270)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.GuardedInterceptor.invoke(GuardedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.BrowseNodeStore$getByPath.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.coreui.BrowseComponent.read(BrowseComponent.groovy:81)
    at com.palominolabs.metrics.guice.ExceptionMeteredInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionMeteredInterceptor.java:49)
    at com.palominolabs.metrics.guice.TimedInterceptor.invoke(TimedInterceptor.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor462.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.softwarementors.extjs.djn.router.dispatcher.DispatcherBase.invokeJavaMethod(DispatcherBase.java:142)
    at com.softwarementors.extjs.djn.router.dispatcher.DispatcherBase.invokeMethod(DispatcherBase.java:133)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.extdirect.internal.ExtDirectServlet$3.invokeMethod(ExtDirectServlet.java:236)
    at com.softwarementors.extjs.djn.router.dispatcher.DispatcherBase.dispatch(DispatcherBase.java:63)
    at com.softwarementors.extjs.djn.router.processor.standard.StandardRequestProcessorBase.dispatchStandardMethod(StandardRequestProcessorBase.java:73)
    at com.softwarementors.extjs.djn.router.processor.standard.json.JsonRequestProcessor.processIndividualRequest(JsonRequestProcessor.java:502)
    at com.softwarementors.extjs.djn.router.processor.standard.json.DefaultJsonRequestProcessorThread.processRequest(DefaultJsonRequestProcessorThread.java:72)
    at com.softwarementors.extjs.djn.servlet.ssm.SsmJsonRequestProcessorThread.processRequest(SsmJsonRequestProcessorThread.java:43)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.extdirect.internal.ExtDirectJsonRequestProcessorThread.access$1(ExtDirectJsonRequestProcessorThread.java:1)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.extdirect.internal.ExtDirectJsonRequestProcessorThread$1.call(ExtDirectJsonRequestProcessorThread.java:61)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.extdirect.internal.ExtDirectJsonRequestProcessorThread$1.call(ExtDirectJsonRequestProcessorThread.java:1)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletScopes$4.call(ServletScopes.java:450)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.extdirect.internal.ExtDirectJsonRequestProcessorThread.processRequest(ExtDirectJsonRequestProcessorThread.java:75)
    at com.softwarementors.extjs.djn.router.processor.standard.json.DefaultJsonRequestProcessorThread.call(DefaultJsonRequestProcessorThread.java:56)
    at com.softwarementors.extjs.djn.router.processor.standard.json.DefaultJsonRequestProcessorThread.call(DefaultJsonRequestProcessorThread.java:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.binary.impl.index.OCompositeKeySerializer.deserializeFromByteBufferObject(OCompositeKeySerializer.java:347)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.binary.impl.index.OCompositeKeySerializer.deserializeFromByteBufferObject(OCompositeKeySerializer.java:46)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.base.ODurablePage.deserializeFromDirectMemory(ODurablePage.java:166)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.sbtree.local.OSBTreeBucket.getKey(OSBTreeBucket.java:266)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.sbtree.local.OSBTreeBucket.find(OSBTreeBucket.java:134)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.sbtree.local.OSBTree.findBucket(OSBTree.java:1679)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.sbtree.local.OSBTree.access$2800(OSBTree.java:69)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.sbtree.local.OSBTree$OSBTreeCursorForward.next(OSBTree.java:1991)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.engine.OSBTreeIndexEngine$OSBTreeIndexCursor.nextEntry(OSBTreeIndexEngine.java:263)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexAbstractCursor.hasNext(OIndexAbstractCursor.java:83)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexChangesWrapper.hasNext(OIndexChangesWrapper.java:138)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.serialIterator(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:1636)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.fetchFromTarget(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:1585)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.fetchValuesFromIndexCursor(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:2466)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.searchForIndexes(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:2280)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.searchInClasses(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:1017)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLResultsetAbstract.assignTarget(OCommandExecutorSQLResultsetAbstract.java:203)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.assignTarget(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:527)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.executeSearch(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:509)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:485)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:70)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.executeCommand(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:3400)
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

I tried cleaning up the packages, re-indexing the feed (which fails) and running the "Repair - Rebuild repository browse) task (also fails).

The repair repo task fails to complete after 1s

```
Failed to run task 'Rebuilding browse tree for internals_snapshots'; 1 failure
```

```
Suppressed: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Error on execution of command: sql.select from browse_node  WHERE repository_name = "internals_snapshots" LIMIT 1000
    DB name="component"
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

Any suggestions on what can cause this ?

Comment: Is upgrading possible?  That version is over a year old, so it's missing any and all fixes.  3.25 is out now.

Comment: Yes that is an option, we are preparing for an upgrade, but i was hoping to resolve this prior to the upgrade. An issue like this can interfere during the upgrade process.
We have an 800GB Blob, so i need to get a test environment setup that can support that so we can do a test upgrade.

Comment: @Nico was you able to find a solution for this issue?